# Version conflict error is being shown, apparently there is no version conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing this error after upgrading my google servces plugin. Apparently there is no version conflict as you can see its 9.2.0, the compiler is giving a completely different error of google services-plugin.
I have searched for it on many places and I have found people are getting this error because they haven't written this at the end:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but I have written it and still getting this error.

Here is what the error looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1` which is newer version as compared to other dependencies with version `9.2.0`. You can simply use latest version of each of them and resolve conflicts.

So either go for `9.2.0`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
```

or for `10.0.1`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

And obviously I would suggest to go for latest version always.

Comment: You are right using latest version  of each of them  resolved the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same version for every thing.

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-aurh:10.0.1'
```